# How to add Canvas tag inside repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, chart.js

Using chartjs successfully generated one pie chart inside repeater .
want to display pie chart for all item inside repeater.
Please let me know good approach to handle this scenario

Code Structure:

Currently first repeater record generate pie chart .

```
<asp:repeater  id="Repeater1" runat="server>
<ItemTemplate>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Another repeater code</td>
   <td>
      <div>
         <canvas id="mychart"></canvas>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to to is make sure every canvas has a unique ID. You can do that by adding the `ItemIndex` to the id.

```
<canvas id="mychart_<%# Container.ItemIndex %>"></canvas>
```

After that you can use JavasScript to build the charts. There you use `<%= Repeater1.Items.Count %>` to get the total item count.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < <%= Repeater1.Items.Count %>; i++) {
            buildCanvas("mychart_" + i);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks solved it by similar approach                                                    <script type="text/javascript">

        var arr = $j("#wrapper Canvas").length;
        
        var i = 0;


        for (i; i < arr; i++) {
            var HiddenJson = $j('#Hdn-wrap input').eq(i);

            LoadChartJs(i, HiddenJson);
        }

    </script>[/Code]